# Does MySQL have a text search that seems to work like Google's?

Tags: mysql, ruby, search, nlp

I'm making a website where the backend uses MySQL and the Ruby gem Sinatra.

My MySQL table has a `LONGTEXT` column with a `FULLTEXT` index.

I've written a MySQL query that's basically this:

```
SELECT Plot 
FROM myTable
WHERE MATCH(Plot) AGAINST('time travel robot')
```

The first result:

`Man on the Moon is a biographical movie on the late comedian Andy Kaufman. Kaufman, along with his role on Taxi (1978), was famous for being the self-declared Intergender Wrestling Champion of the world. After beating women time and time again, Jerry Lawler (who plays himself in the movie), a professional wrestler, got tired of seeing all of this and decided to challenge Kaufman to a match. In most of the matches the two had, Lawler prevailed with the piledriver, which is a move by spiking an opponent head-first into the mat. One of the most famous moments in this feud was in the early 80s when Kaufman threw coffee on Lawler on Late Night with David Letterman (1982), got into fisticuffs with Lawler, and proceeded to sue NBC.`

Even though I like this movie, it has nothing to do with time traveling or robots.

I don't know Google's search algorithm, but I would like to know if MySQL has a search function that ranks results based on how close together the inputted words are.

In my case, I'd like the most relevant results to have the words "time," "travel" and "robot" as close together as possible.

And it would be nice if my dream function could also get variations on the words, like "travelling" or "robots."

How much of this is possible with MySQL? Or with Ruby?

Or should I go with something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

Google does searching by performing indexing on large n-gram data using solr(lucene). [see](http://www.solrtutorial.com/basic-solr-concepts.html)

Using mysql with ruby you can do it but surely on large data it will not be that much fast and effective. But for small data, you would be happy to see result.

A `database index` is a data structure that improves the speed of data retrieval operations on a database table at the cost of additional writes and storage space to maintain the index data structure. see [indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)

There are various data structure techniques used for this indexing purpose. Those you can also apply on mysql with ruby. To get basic idea check this [tutorial](https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations)

So if you have large data set, thta performing some indexing technique on that data, now when your search on that indexed data for your query `time travel robot` that it will automatically show you most related result.